# PDO how to INSERT when there's a new visitor? PHP & PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Inserting unique visitors to my table doesn't work. I'm using PDO. What's wrong?

SELECT and show rowCount works perfectly fine, but inserting the new unique visitor doesn't.

```
// Get visitors (WORKS)
try {
    $statement = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `counter`");
    $statement->execute();
    $row_count = $statement->rowCount();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

// New visitor (NOT WORKING)
$ip_address = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$date = date("Y/m/d H:i:s"); 

if ($row_count == 0) {
    try {
        $statement2 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `counter` (`id`, `ip_address`, `visit_date`) 
                                                    VALUES (`NULL`, `:ip_address`, `:date`)");
        $statement2->bindParam(':ip_address', $ip_address);
        $statement2->bindParam(':date', $date);
        $statement2->execute();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

// Show Unique Visitors (WORKS)
echo $row_count;
```

MySQL structure of my table "counter":
[image: MySQL Structure]

I want a unique visitor counter, showing how many have visited my whole website

Comment: You haven't explained what doesn't work. But I can see two problems: firstly your date format is incorrect, it should be `Y-m-d H:i:s` and secondly `NULL` should not be enclosed in backticks.

Comment: If your id field was created as an AUTO_INCREMENT field, you shouldn't even need to set it in the query at all.

Comment: Nick, nothing is being inserted into my table. Whenever a person comes into the website, I want to INSERT data (id, ip, date) into the table. I have corrected the mistakes you mentioned, still not working

Comment: Chris White, ok I have made it to AUTO_INCREMENT and removed it from the query, ty

Comment: [link](https://i.gyazo.com/5500f5bb6f6a3b3c06859a460d86c028.png) This is the output now

Comment: Should be as simple as `$statement2 = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO \`counter\` (\`ip_address\`) VALUES (:ip_address)"); $statement2->bindParam(':ip_address', $ip_address);` Which will just use the default `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` you have set on the `visit_date` table.

Comment: (IGNORE THIS)It's not unique, do you know how to check if ip_address already exists?

Comment: Nvm it's unique, I just messed something up